# Find mutiple special character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have to found in multiple Logfiles entrys in logfiles. The returm musst include the following (*) (*)
so like in line with Weber Tom (PRD) (PRD); but not Huser Andri (PRD)

----Log File----

```
DEBUG - [2022-04-16 04:47:06,337] - [30] Get-AdUserProperty - existingDisplayName=Weber Tom (PRD) (PRD)
DEBUG - [2022-04-16 04:47:06,337] - [37] Get-AdUserProperty - existingDisplayName=Huser Andri (PRD)
DEBUG - [2022-04-16 04:47:06,353] - [35] changePostalAddress: False
DEBUG - [2022-04-16 04:47:06,353] - [35] PostalAddress.Street: Bäckerstrasse
DEBUG - [2022-04-16 04:47:06,353] - [35] changeOfficeAddress: False
```

---

the Problem is that Regex cannot search (). It's for Regex Funktion blocked. Also multiple Words in one Line with .* does not work for this.

How can I found Entries like this

```
(PRD) (PRD)
```

or

```
(PRI) (PRI)strong text
```

or

```
(PRO) (PRO)
```

Hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: Notepad++ has no problem searching for `(PRD)`  in Normal mode, or in regex mode use `\(PRD\) `. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(\(.+?\))\h+\1.*$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    (           # start group 1
        \(          # openning parens, have to be escaped
        .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
        \)          # closing parens
    )           # end group 1
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \1          # backreference to group 1 (i.e. the same value)
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much and have a nice Day... ;-)

Comment: @Pedro: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)